# Run app in background only if audio os playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to run an app in background only if audio is playing?

I have made an app and I want that when the app goes in background, it will check if audio is playing or not. If audio is playing, then the app will run in background else the app will close.

TO DO this I have set in info.plist

```
Application does not run in background          YES
```

Then audio is not playing in background.

Now to run audio I set

```
if(AUDIO_IS_PLAYING==NO){

    exit(0);

}
```

But I think apple will not permit this.

Any other ways if you know to run the app in background only if audio is playing else it will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use notifications:

Following notification is posted when the application enters the background.

```
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
```

Following notification is posted when the application becomes active.

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
```

Add notification observer in function

```
//Adding observer for notification
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Your other code goes here

    // Adding observer for notification when application entered the background
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}

// This method will be called when application entered in background
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:(id)sender
{
    // Do whatever you want when application in background
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to know when app goes in background how to kill the app if audio is not playing. exit(0) is valid?

Comment: **It is not good idea to terminate you application.**

you can call exit but there are changes of rejection. instead of that use applicationWillTerminate